# Where is the native binary app for windows today?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

Well, trying to build a simple exe in visual studio 2012, with c++ win32 console app, just with a 
printf("-----");
After build the release version, its running ok.

When transfer to another windows 7 clean installation, at running i get notice that the MSVCP110.DLL is missing...

Its not a native app ??? why extern dll is needed ?

In old win95 I make many executables with visual C 6 and its run standalone withou any dll.

I will always deplay this dll's with the "native" exe ?

Comment: Welcome to the evils of shared libraries. You should be able to change the linker and compiler settings to compile with static libraries. In addition, it looks as if you're linking to the MFC runtime. You shouldn't need to do that for a console app.

Comment: @Richard msvcpxxx is the C++ runtime library DLL, I don't see any mention of MFC in the question. Static linking to the runtime libraries is not the right answer except for the most trivial programs.

Comment: Question is clearly on-topic.  Voted to reopen.

Comment: hi, no MFC man, i select option "multithread MT" instead of "multithread dll" and seems to be running without this dll, I will make more tests to check

Comment: @Leonardo:  Don't just bang on the mouse until your program seems to work.  Try to understand what you're doing.

Comment: @Leonardo Given that John took the time to answer the question, I've voted to reopen, despite voting to close originally. The reason I did that was because of this: *In old win95 I make many executables with visual C 6*. That sentence makes your question seem like a trolling attempt. Were you living under a rock since Win95 days until now? Linking to the runtime libraries has been around for a long long time.

Comment: @Praetorian:  You should see the comment that I edited out of the original post.  Super trollish.

Comment: @Praetorian thanks for that. It's been a while since I wrote on windows. However in this case I would say that static linking is exactly what the OP needs - he needs to transfer an executable without dependencies.
It seems to me that shared libraries were once necessary because of available physical memory. These days static linking can offer better performance (link time optimisation) and a reduced working set. I actually favour static libraries whenever possible.

Comment: For many reasons, depend on king of app, the static is much much much better option. So, today, MS try to put the static version in a hide place.. you loose much more time finding option that build de app.. sorry for my inconvenience

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you write a C++ program, you use a few low-level libraries to interface with the machine.  The C++ Standard Library is one example.  Consider for example, `new`.  When you call `new` in your program, you're invoking a piece of code that implements that functionality.  Where is that actual code?

It's in a library.  That library is deployed in a few different ways.  One way is through dynamic linking, where the library is in the form of a DLL that needs to be present on the machine where you run your program.  That's what `MSVCP110.DLL` is -- it's one of the library files your program was compiled against.  Another way is to use static linking, where the code from that library is compiled *directly* in to your program.  This results in a signifigant increase in the size of your application, but the other side of that coin is you don't need those library files to be on your target machine.  You also need to make sure that other libraries your program use are also built against the same static library.  If your program shares data with other programs, you further may need to ensure that *those* programs use the same static libraries.

Microsoft and Windows aren't unique in this.  The same thing happens under Linux, albeit the libraries have different names.

There are pros and cons to using either shared libraries (eg dynamic linking) or static libraries.  It's simple and catchy to say "gahrrr I hate shared libraries" but unless you understand why either is appropriate in what situation you stand to deploy a poorly-designed  program.

Comment: please mention and link to the Visual C++ redistributables, answer is not very complete without a practical solution (other than statically linking everything).